# Crystal Reports, accept NULL values through a parameter

Tags: parameters, null, crystal-reports

I am creating a report using Crystal Reports and I have to filter the values using parameters. So far I have used the code below to filter the data in the select expert.

```
{ACTION_MES_CMB_R.EVAL_ID} = {?Evaluation} and
{ACTION_MES_CMB_R.EMP_NUMBER} = {?Employee} and
{PARAMETER.PARA_NAME} = "COMPANY_COPYRIGHTS" and
{VW_ACTION_MES_CMB_R.GOAL_VERSION_NO} = {?Goal_Version}
```

In addition to that I also want to get the data that has null values for `VW_ACTION_MES_CMB_R.GOAL_VERSION_NO` .
So the code shold be changed to something like this to accept DB NULL values,

```
{VW_ACTION_MES_CMB_R.GOAL_VERSION_NO} = {?Goal_Version} or /**NULL**/
```

Please help me do this. I hope you can understand the question. Thank you.

Comment: is `null` selected by user during providing input to the report?

Comment: the user have to select a value and by default the null value should be selected.

Comment: You need to add null as default parameter that means don't type null instead add a row in parameter window without entering anything not even space and use the same code `{VW_ACTION_MES_CMB_R.GOAL_VERSION_NO} = {?Goal_Version} `

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem.

```
(isnull({VW_ACTION_MES_CMB_R.GOAL_VERSION_NO}) or {VW_ACTION_MES_CMB_R.GOAL_VERSION_NO} = {?Goal_Version}) and
{VW_ACTION_MES_CMB_R.EVAL_ID} = {?Evaluation} and
{VW_ACTION_MES_CMB_R.EMP_NUMBER} = {?Employee} and
{PARAMETER.PARA_NAME} = "COMPANY_COPYRIGHTS"
```